# Attempting to load C# solution in Monodevelop, getting error: 'Unknown Solution Type'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I try to load a solution this is the error messagebox I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKUwP.png

It was originally a Visual Studio 2010 project in Windows which I'm trying to port to different platforms (i.e. iOS, Android, OSX, Linux).

Comment: .contentproj? Why aren't you using the .sln files?

Comment: I'm loading the .sln file  and getting that error, not sure why it's referring to .contentproj.

Comment: is it an XNA project?  Are those supported by MD/MT?

Comment: It is an XNA project (that's how it was created in Visual Studio), I'm trying to load the project up to see if I acn get it compiling using MonoGame or ExEn. Could that be the cause of the problem? If so what should I look into removing from the sln/csproj files to get it to load in MonoDevelop? Or should I just build a project and create the files and folders from scratch?

Comment: Just wanted to add it's not just the .contentproj it's not loading but also the .csproj. I guess I can understand .contentproj not loading (I'll have to see how MonoGame handles XNAs content pipeline) but .csproj is pretty standard with C# Visual Studio projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error loading the solution, it's an error loading the projects inside the solution. It seems that those particular projects are project types or subtypes that are not supported by MonoDevelop.

In particular, it looks the the *XNA Content* project type and the *XNA* subtype (or flavor) of the C# project type. Note that VS wouldn't be able to open these project either if you didn't have  XNA installed.

Comment: ah fair enough. Guess I'll just keep creating a generic MonoDevelop project and manually adding in the class files and such from the C# content projs...